# command not running in cron (systemctl suspend)

Tags: cron, systemd, suspend

I have this cronjob set :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/systemctl suspend
```

And it is not working. But I can run it in a shell and it works. I don't understand what could be not working.

**EDIT**
Redirecting error output to `/tmp/error` gives this :

```
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
```

My question is then : Are cronjobs run as a special user (`cron` for example), which would explain that my user can run the command, but not `cron` itself?

Additional explanation :

- This is a minimal example to show a problem I have in a script (that makes more sense than the single command provided here)
- `systemctl` is part of `systemd`. I think reboot, shutdown, suspend are working with a non-root user with `systemd`. Anyway, it is working on my system.
- Finally, I use Arch Linux and `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/sbin` are all symlinks to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What does the command do when you run it in the shell?

Comment: It suspends my computer

Comment: And do you want that to happen every minute? Your `systemctl` is in `/usr/bin` and it accepts `suspend` like that? What *nix are you using?

Comment: No, it is an example. It is actually in a script that suspends when battery power is low. But this is the part in my script that is not working. I tried to give a minimal example of the problem (even if this seems to make no sense).

Comment: I am using Arch linux and /bin, /sbin, /usr/sbin are all symlinks to /usr/bin.

Comment: OK,since this question is collecting close-votes, please [edit] it to add this extra info. Your distro is important (`systemctl suspend`doesn't work on Debian or RedHat distros) and so is explaining that you don't actually want to do what you're showing :). Also, try adding `2> /tmp/error` or something to capture any errors you might be getting. Finally, tell us which user is running this crontab.

Answer (score 7):

I can't really answer as such but I think I can point you in the right direction. I found this in the Arch Wiki [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Power_management) of `systemd`:

> [polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) is necessary for power management. If you are in a local systemd-logind user session and no other session is active, the following commands will work without root privileges. If not (for example, because another user is logged into a tty), systemd will automatically ask you for the root password.
>
> [list of various systemctl commands]
>
> systemctl suspend

This suggests to me the following possibilities:

1. You have another user logged in. Perhaps you have logged in via a tty?
2. `cron` runs its commands using `/bin/sh`. [By default](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash_as_/bin/sh), on Arch this is a symlink to `/bin/bash`. This would mean that `cron` is starting a non-interactive bash shell which then detects that there is another user session running (yours), so it does not have the right to run `systemctl` despite running as your user.

So, if your problem is because `cron` is not allowed to run `systemctl` because you are already logged in, you might be able to get around that by playing with [polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) but I have no experience there so I can't help.

Comment: Thank you! The first option can be eliminated as I am able to execute the command in a shell. But I will do some more research about the second option.

Comment: @Gradient did you discover how to fix this? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Could you please explain the second possibility in more detail ? Is there any way to confirm that this is indeed the problem ? I executed `w` and `uptime` from the scripts run by cron. Their outputs indicated the there was only user. So, does this mean that there is some other problem ?

Answer (score 3):

An easy workaround is to use root's crontab instead of your own. Edit it with:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

instead of:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Comment: It runs the commands as root rather than your user.

Comment: This should not be a recommended practice... make the command work for the user.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier solution without sudo, by using **`systemd-run`**:

The important thing is that you have to set/export the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable for the related user.
Simply create a script named `systemctl-suspend` or something, with the following lines:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# This is a workaround script to be able to use 'systemctl suspend' in user-cron
PATH=/usr/bin
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/"$(id -u "$LOGNAME")"/bus
systemd-run --user systemctl suspend
```

and make it executable, then copy that script file to a folder such as `/usr/local/bin`.

Finally, start the script in the user's crontab just like this:

```
0 22 * * * /usr/local/bin/systemctl-suspend
```

Tested on Debian 10 (buster).

Comment: On an Ubuntu 20.04 `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` since `/bin/systemctl`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the system crontab, then you forget the user field. Try:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/systemctl suspend
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a user field? I have never seen a cronjob with it before. Anyway, the command works when I run it as a user in a shell.

Comment: @Gradient there is a user field if you are using `/etc/crontab`, is this a crontab you created with `cron -e` as your normal user?

Comment: It is a crontab I created with `crontab -e` as a normal user.

Comment: your normal user account probably doesn't have permission to run `systemctl suspend` without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786225/173003):

> [The other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/785596/173003) is great! But
>   it requires root cron.
>
> If you want to hibernate from non-sudo
>   cron, there are 2 options:
>
> ### 1. Using [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit)
>
> Make a file containing the following:
>
> ```
> [Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
> ResultAny=yes
> ```
>
> named `com.0.enable-hibernation-from-cron.pkla` in the directory
>   `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`.
>
> Explanation is given
>   [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289123/explanation-of-file-org-freedesktop-login1-policy).
>
> ### 2. Using [visudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)
>
> Quoting from
>   [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/allow_users_to_shutdown#Users_without_sudo_privileges):
>
> > If users should only be allowed to use shutdown commands, but not have
> >     other sudo privileges, then, as root, add the following to the end of
> >     *`/etc/sudoers`* using the `visudo` command.
> >
> > ```
> > user hostname =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl poweroff,/usr/bin/systemctl halt,/usr/bin/systemctl reboot
> > ```
> >
> > Substitute `user` for your username and `hostname` for the machine's hostname.
> >     Now your user can shutdown with `sudo systemctl poweroff`, and reboot
> >     with `sudo systemctl reboot`. Users wishing to power down a system can
> >     also use `sudo systemctl halt`.
> >     Use the NOPASSWD: tag only if you do not want to be prompted for your password.
>
> In my case, the exact line is:
>
> ```
> anmol ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl hibernate
> ```
>
> (Note that the location of `systemctl` might be different on your system.)
>
> After this, you can write `sudo systemctl hibernate` fron cron to
>   hibernate.
>
> Note: Directly modifying *`/etc/sudoers`* is
>   [bad](https://superuser.com/q/869144/241498);
>   instead make a custom sudoers file under *`/etc/sudoers.d/`* using the
>   command - `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/custom`.

Answer (score -2):

You need use systemd config file in `/etc/systemd/system`

```
[Unit]
Description=Pimcore Events Processor

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php run something
Restart=always
WatchdogSec=300 #in seconds
User=www-data
Group=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```