# Explanation of file - org.freedesktop.login1.policy

Tags: systemd, power-management, shutdown, authorization, polkit

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

There is a file located at `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy` which seems to control the permissions regarding shutdown/suspend/hibernate options.

In this file, the revelant options are in this format:

```
<defaults>
  <allow_any>no</allow_any>
  <allow_inactive>auth_admin_keep</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

corresponding to every action (shutdown, suspend etc.).
[Here](http://pastebin.com/SwKJN9Dq) is the full version of that file.

I want to know the meaning of `allow_any`, `allow_inactive` and `allow_active` options.
What do they mean exactly ?

The reason for my curiosity is that I want to hibernate non-interactively without root (from cron), but am getting [authorization errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785509/hibernating-from-cron).

And it seems that those errors can be solved by modifying this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From section **DECLARING ACTIONS** of [polkit - Authorization Framework](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/polkit.8.html):

> defaults
>
> ```
>        This element is used to specify implicit authorizations for
>        clients.
>
>        Elements that can be used inside defaults includes:
>
>        allow_any
>            Implicit authorizations that apply to any client. Optional.
>
>        allow_inactive
>            Implicit authorizations that apply to clients in inactive
>            sessions on local consoles. Optional.
>
>        allow_active
>            Implicit authorizations that apply to clients in active
>            sessions on local consoles. Optional.
>
>        Each of the allow_any, allow_inactive and allow_active elements can
>        contain the following values:
>
>        no
>            Not authorized.
>
>        yes
>            Authorized.
>
>        auth_self
>            Authentication by the owner of the session that the client
>            originates from is required.
>
>        auth_admin
>            Authentication by an administrative user is required.
>
>        auth_self_keep
>            Like auth_self but the authorization is kept for a brief
>            period.
>
>        auth_admin_keep
>            Like auth_admin but the authorization is kept for a brief
>            period.
> ```

I hope this makes it clear for you.

Comment: What is a `session` exactly ? What is the difference between `active` and `inactive` sessions ? What values do I use to solve the problem I mentioned at the end ?

Comment: Are you using `systemctl hibernate` command?

Comment: Yes. I am using that.

Comment: OK I don't have that command in my system to test. What if you try the command when you are the only locally logged in user. Do you get the same error?

Comment: As far as I know, I am the only logged in user. I am running it on my personal laptop. I ran `w` and `uptime` from `cron` and got indication  of 1 user only.

Comment: And if having `yes` in all the options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41032/discussion-between-coffemug-and-anmol-singh-jaggi).

Answer (score 4):

[This link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Actions) contains the information given by [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289128/42552) in a better way.

Especially this part:

> The defaults tag is where the permissions or lack thereof are located.
>   It contains three settings: `allow_any`, `allow_inactive`, and `allow_active`.
>   Inactive sessions are generally remote sessions (SSH,
>   VNC, etc.) whereas active sessions are logged directly into the
>   machine on a TTY or an X display.
>   `allow_any` is the setting encompassing both scenarios.
>
> For each of these settings the following options are available:
>
> ```
> no: The user is not authorized to carry out the action. There is therefore no need for authentication.
> yes: The user is authorized to carry out the action without any authentication.
> auth_self: Authentication is required but the user need not be an administrative user.
> auth_admin: Authentication as an administrative user is require.
> auth_self_keep: The same as auth_self but, like sudo, the authorization lasts a few minutes.
> auth_admin_keep: The same as auth_admin but, like sudo, the authorization lasts a few minutes.
> ```

Also, [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) is the official manual page of polkit.

Hibernation can be made to be turned on from cron by changing the `no` to `yes` inside the `allow_any` tags under the actions `org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate` and `org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions`.

**But this is not a recommended solution** as it can be erased during future upgrades.

Instead you can make a file containing the following:

```
[Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
```

named `com.0.enable-hibernation-from-cron.pkla` in the directory `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` to achieve the same effect.

An even better solution using `visudo` is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786225/173003).

Comment: This is the better answer than the other one with copy-pasting man page. Great job done!

Comment: @Anwar Thanks! I accepted that answer because firstly, it made me aware about polkit without which my answer wouldn't have been possible, and secondly, accepting my own answer seemed a bit weird.

Comment: In my opinion, the correct and most accurate answer should be accepted. That helps future visitor. Since here only 2 answer is given, I see no problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian sid this work for me:

1. In `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/cron-suspend.rules` file add:

   ```js
   polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
       if (subject.user == "my-user" && (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-session")) {
           return polkit.Result.YES;
       }
   });
   ```
2. Restart the service:

   ```bash
   systemctl restart polkit
   ```

OBS: change `suspend` to `hibernete` if needed.