# systemctl doesn't work from crontab

Tags: scripting, cron, kali-linux, systemctl

I'm trying to run a script calling `systemctl` from crontab but the command is not being executed. Other scripts work fine from crontab. The script works when executed in a terminal.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date &>> ~/Desktop/logs/resiliostatus.txt
systemctl --user status resilio-sync | sed -ne '1,3p' &>> ~/Desktop/logs/resiliostatus.txt
exit 0
```

This is the output to my logfile:

```
Thu Jan 17 02:17:17 CET 2019
● resilio-sync.service - Resilio Sync service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/resilio-sync.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-01-17 01:01:55 CET; 1h 15min ago
Thu Jan 17 03:00:01 CET 2019
Thu Jan 17 04:00:01 CET 2019
Thu Jan 17 05:00:01 CET 2019
```

The first entry is how it should look like when called from the terminal. But as you can see the calls from crontab only execute `date` and not `systemctl`

This is how crontab looks like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/lib/systemd

# m h  dom mon dow   command

*/15 * * * * /root/Desktop/backupscripts/cputempscript
*/30 * * * * /root/Desktop/backupscripts/ipdnsscript
0 * * * * /root/Desktop/backupscripts/ntpscript
*/5 * * * * /root/Desktop/backupscripts/resiliostatscript 2> /tmp/error
```

The first three scripts work fine, the last one doesnt.
The error I save to /tmp/error: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

- I'm logged in as root. No other user is logged in. Crontab is configured as `sudo crontab -e`
- Environment: Kali Linux (re4son kernel, sticky-fingers) on RPi 3B+
- I read this [similar thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90817/command-not-running-in-cron-systemctl-suspend) but it is also unresolved.

How can I fix this?

Comment: fwiw, I would think it is caused by your systems `/etc/pam.d/cron` not invoking `pam_systemd`.  Some systems do it, and some don't.

Comment: there's indeed no hint to pam_systemd in this file. How can I correctly configure this?

Comment: well, I tried adding `session include pam_systemd.so` to `/etc/pam.d/cron`, not really knowing what I'm doing, rebooted, and apparently that completely broke cron.  In `var/log/syslog` it says `CRON[804]: Permission denied.` No commands were executed. @sourcejedi

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431896/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423632/ .